# Updating authorization of HttpClient whilst maintaining concurrency?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

What I'm wanting to implement is a HttpClient that can get a new bearer token whenever a 401 is thrown by the server. The token expires every 30 minutes and I would like to just update that, but modifying the headers isn't threadsafe (as far as I'm aware) and will cause issues if one thread tries to update the authorisation whilst another is trying to make a request.

```
public class MyCustomClient : HttpClient
{
    public MyCustomClient(Configuration config)
        :base()
    {
        this.BaseAddress = new Uri(config.ServiceUrl);
        this.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
        this.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public async Task UpdateBearerTokenAsync()
    {
        var token = "123" // assume this was retrieved from server successfully
        this.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    }
}
```

What I ideally need is for only one re-authorization to be going on at once, and for all other calls to wait if the client is currently trying to re-authenticate.

The first part I think I can do by using a SemaphoreSlim

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _bearerTokenSemaphore;

public MyCustomClient(Configuration config)
    :base()
{

    _bearerTokenSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
    _bearerTokenSemaphore.Release();

    this.BaseAddress = new Uri(config.ServiceUrl);
    this.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
    this.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
}

public async Task<bool> UpdateBearerTokenAsync()
{
    if (!_bearerTokenSemaphore.Wait(0))
    {
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        var token = "123" // assume this was retrieved from server successfully using an asynchronous method
        this.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        return true;
    }
    finally { _bearerTokenSemaphore.Release(); }
}
```

However I'm not sure of a good way of making all other calls wait if authorisation is currently occurring. I tried something like

```
public new async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string uri)
{
    await _bearerTokenSemaphore.WaitAsync();
    _bearerTokenSemaphore.Release();

    return await base.GetAsync(uri);
}
```

But this just seemed to deadlock

EDIT:

The above didn't work because I never released the sempahore after instantiating it (woops). So this does seem to work now, but I am still open to better suggestions as I'm really not happy with this implementation